# The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager

Tags: sql-server, .net-framework, c#, mvc

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)

Logs collected from application server

> time=12/18/2018-15:58:08.204       seq=115         eventid=TRACING_STARTED
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.343    seq=116         eventid=TRANSACTION_ABORTING
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.343    seq=117         eventid=TRANSACTION_ABORTED
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:58.705    seq=118         eventid=TRACING_STOPPED

Logs collected from database server (SQL Server)

> time=12/18/2018-15:58:30.302       seq=386         eventid=TRANSACTION_BEGUN
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:30.302    seq=387         eventid=RM_ENLISTED_IN_TRANSACTION
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.349    seq=388         eventid=RECEIVED_ABORT_REQUEST_FROM_BEGINNER
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.349    seq=389         eventid=TRANSACTION_ABORTING
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.349    seq=390         eventid=RM_ISSUED_ABORT
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.349    seq=391         eventid=RM_ACKNOWLEDGED_ABORT
>   time=12/18/2018-15:58:36.349    seq=392         eventid=TRANSACTION_ABORTED

Which show the two machines were able to communicate with each other, a transaction was started but then application sends a message to abort the transaction.

It happens intermittently, could anyone let me know what may cause an application to abort the transaction?

The code block causing this exception is of the given form

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
{
    // Data insertion
    // DbContext.SaveChanges()

    // Data update
    // DbContext.SaveChanges()

    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```